# Assigning Field Symbols to Internal Table

Tags: abap

I'm trying upload Excel file to internal table in ABAP. I'm using function `GUI_UPLOAD` and then `SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING`. At last I have field sybmbol `<gt_data>` with data from Excel file.

```
DATA(lo_data_ref) = lo_excel_ref->if_fdt_doc_spreadsheet~get_itab_from_worksheet(
                                             lv_woksheetname ).
*-- Excel work sheet data in dyanmic internal table
    ASSIGN lo_data_ref->* TO <gt_data>.
```

| A [CString] | B [CString] |
| --- | --- |
| data1 | data11 |
| data2 | data22 |
| data3 | data33 |

How I can iterate `<gt_data>` to internal table? I would try like below, but I received dump.

```
 TYPES: BEGIN OF lty_test,
           A  TYPE string,
           B TYPE string,
         END OF lty_test.

  DATA: lt_test_table    TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF lty_test.
```

Comment: Try to post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: didn't you try to check sy-subrc after `get_itab_from_worksheet()` not ot receive dump?

Comment: When did you get dump? Could you give us more detail about dump line?

Comment: I have tried ```LOOP AT <gt_data> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data>).
    DO 10 TIMES.
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING <ls_data> TO lt_test_table.
    ENDDO.
  ENDLOOP. ```
And received dump

```The MOVE-CORRESPONDING statement can only be used on operands if both
operands are structured types or internal tables.
If the KEEPING TARGET LINES addition is used, only tables can be used
as operands.

One of these conditions has not met here: Operand "<LS_DATA>" has type
 "DEEP_STRUCTURE".
Operand "LT_TEST_TABLE" has type "INTERNAL_TABLE".```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, you want to read excel rows with this code.

```
LOOP AT <gt_data> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data>).
ENDLOOP.
```

I am not sure struct of <ls_data> but I think you can read it with index for get to know main idea.

Could you try it like below?

```
CHECK <gt_data> IS ASSIGNED.
"It's column count for excel file. It can be found dynamically.
DATA(lv_column_count) = 10.
"Loop for rows.
LOOP AT <gt_data> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data>).
  "Loop for columns
  DO lv_column_count.
   ASSIGN COMPONENT sy-index OF <ls_dat> TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<lfs_value>).
  ENDDO.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. In <lfs_value> I have String value. and how to populate internal table, like `lt_sflight`?

Comment: Just append <lfs_value> to your new internal table line. Don't forget match exact value for new internal table line when you assigned <lfs_value>.  You can do it with index number, field name etc. It depends your approach.

Comment: Tkanks. I don't know how to do it, now. But I will be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So first you need to declare a structure for the internal table and each field in the structure should have type "string".

```
Types:begin of ty_upload,
    Field1 type string,
    Field2 type string,
   End of ty_upload.
Data:it_upload type standard table of ty_upload.
It_upload[] = <gt_data>
```

Now internal table it_upload should have the data from the field value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    file = 'C:\xyz.XLS'.

  CALL FUNCTION 'ALSM_EXCEL_TO_INTERNAL_TABLE'
    EXPORTING
      filename                = file
      i_begin_col             = '1'
      i_begin_row             = '1'
      i_end_col               = '5'
      i_end_row               = '6000'
    TABLES
      intern                  = xcel
    EXCEPTIONS
      inconsistent_parameters = 1
      upload_ole              = 2
      OTHERS                  = 3.

LOOP AT xcel.
  " xcel is an internal table and has field xcel-value
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Yes, it works like that. But my issue was using `GUI_UPLOAD` and then `SCMS_BINARY_TO_XSTRING`. I can upload file with more then one Spreadsheet. I have data in field symbol <gt_data>, I iterated: `  LOOP AT <gt_data> ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_data>).`. But I don't kno what next. In <ls_data> I have deep structure.

Comment: Do you know the component of the deep structure <ls_data> which you want to read ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).